# Sending email via PHP

Tags: php

I am currently trying to send an email from an hmtl form using the following example:

http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php

When I click the submit button, it goes to the next page, but it all comes up as plain text, and nothing is done. Is there another step I am missing to make this php file? In my folder it says it is saved as a php file.

I have done exactly what the example tells to do and I come up with that problem. What am I not doing?

Or can you suggest a better way of doing what I am attempting?

Comment: Add some of *your* code to the question

Comment: We're missing server architecture -- Apache? IIS? If you create `info.php` with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it and execute that, do you also get "plain text"? If so, see the [first answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11513096/463139) to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely issue is that your server is not configured to run PHP files. Maybe you don't have PHP installed, or if you are using shared hosting then perhaps you don't have PHP enabled.

Or you're trying to run it from your own computer, which won't work unless you install server software.

Comment: I am trying to run it from my own computer since I was testing and the example did not mention the fact that I needed any thing other than the two files.  That would explain it. Thank you very much Kolink

Answer (score 0):

Even if you install a server software ex. wamp etc. You will need to setup a mail server to send mails from server. I would suggest getting a hosting. If you are just testing then you can use a free hosting also for now. There are many out there.